# Sitecore package installation is failed through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I am getting below error while installing the packages in Sitecore through Powershell.

[image: packages in Sitecore through Powershell.]

Comment: What error did you mean? Please edit the original question

Comment: I think you forgot to attach the error message.

Comment: did you try to install the package without Power Shell ?

Comment: Sitecore package installation failed through Powershell.
I have attached the screenshot. please find it.
yes, I tried without powershell, its working fine.

Comment: Evidently the process of installing the package has timed out.  There's a few reasons this might happen, but a good one is that the current w3wp.exe has a lock on various files that the package may be trying to replace.  This might cause a deadlock - honestly I've never seen this happen but it is at least theoretically possible.  As @SitecoreClimber mentioned, I would try to install the package normally to see if it's a problem with the package or PowerShell.  If the latter, you can raise a ticket at [SPE Github](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/)

Comment: I tried normally, its installing. But if I tried with Powershell, I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar question reported on the community https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/7/t/1173

The issue is that the web service we built encounters a timeout with the long running process of the installation wizard. We provide a solution in which you can create a background *ScriptSession* job that you can later retrieve.

In our [gitbook](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/remoting.html) we provide this example.

```
Import-Module -Name SPE
$session = New-ScriptSession -Username admin -Password b -ConnectionUri http://remotesitecore

$job = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Start-ScriptSession -ScriptBlock {
        # Replace the contents of this scriptblock with your installation steps. 
        # I just put $true there so something would come back.
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
        [PSCustomObject]@{"IsComplete"=$true}
    }
}

$keepRunning = $true
while($keepRunning) {
    $done = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
        $scriptSession = Get-ScriptSession -Id $params.JobId
        $scriptSession.State -ne "Busy"
    } -Arguments @{"JobId" = $job.ID} 

    if($done) {
        $keepRunning = $false

        Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
            $scriptSession = Get-ScriptSession -Id $params.JobId
            if($scriptSession.State -ne "Busy") {
                $scriptSession | Receive-ScriptSession
            }
        } -Arguments @{"JobId" = $job.ID}    
    } else {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
    }
}
```

Expect to see updates to the book for simplified a usage with the release of SPE 4.

Comment: I tried that code. But getting following error
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aWRrB.jpg

Answer (score 0):

#### This is sample code

```
Import-Module -Name "C:\Scripts_31DEC\SPE Remoting-3.3\SPE"
$session = New-ScriptSession -Username admin -Password b -ConnectionUri http://quuintranet
$job = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Start-ScriptSession -ScriptBlock {
        # Replace the contents of this scriptblock with your installation steps. 
        # I just put $true there so something would come back.

        Install-Package -Path "C:\Scripts_31DEC\quutest_ow.zip" -InstallMode Overwrite
        [PSCustomObject]@{"IsComplete"=$true}
    }
}

$keepRunning = $true
while($keepRunning) {
    $done = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
        $scriptSession = Get-ScriptSession -Id $params.JobId
        $scriptSession.State -ne "Busy"
    } -Arguments @{"JobId" = $job.ID} 

    if($done) {
        $keepRunning = $false

        Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
            $scriptSession = Get-ScriptSession -Id $params.JobId
            if($scriptSession.State -ne "Busy") {
                $scriptSession | Receive-ScriptSession
            }
        } -Arguments @{"JobId" = $job.ID}    
    } else {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
    }
}
```

Comment: I submitted an edit to your script so you could have a working example.